# gnuplot linewidth and line type with terminal postscript

Tags: bash, gnuplot

In gnuplot I've using `set term postscript enhanced eps color` as well as `lw 5` and `lt 1, 2 and 3` , for three different graphs.

Due to the width of the graphs the line types don't look so different for the three cases.

If I decrease the value of `lw`  to `2` stuffs start getting better, but I'd like to keep using the `lw 5` and at the same time be able to use the different line types. Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

Follow two graphs. Using `set term postscript enhanced eps color dashed`,

[image]

and  `set term epscairo color dashed`:

[image]

In both cases I've used `lw 4`.

The version with `epscairo` looks better, but still the dashed-dot-dot-dashed, looks awful, close to `f(x)=1` for `sin(2x)`

Comment: That has nothing to do with dashed or not, just increase the sampling rate with `set samples 1000`.

Comment: `set sample` is only related with built-in function? Or, if I have my own data it will help as well?

Comment: Yes, this doesn't affect data plot. There you have only as many samples as you have data points. If you need this, you can smooth your data with e.g. `smooth cspline`. Still, this isn't related at all to dashed or solid lines.

Comment: great!! `smooth cspline` did the work. Should I modify my question to then have your (this one) answer as accepted?

Comment: No, I think you can leave it this way. You would have to rewrite the question completely, and the two existing answers would be superfluous. Only, next time, please provide enough and concise information from the beginning ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a general problem of dashed lines with the postscript terminal: For some internal reasons, the points aren't drawn as one continuous line, but every 100 points the line is interrupted by a `moveto` operation. This can lead to very strange results for dashed lines.

A pathological example is

```
set terminal postscript eps mono dashed dl 10 lw 5
set samples 200
set output 'test.eps'
plot x lt 2
```

As you can see, the center dash is much longer than the others. Try using the `epscairo` terminal and see if this works better.

[image]

Comment: Well, then you should come up with some example images to finish this happy guessing...

Comment: I want to upload a .eps, could you tell me how you did it?

Comment: You can't. I used `epstopdf file.eps file.pdf && pdftocairo -png -r 100 file.pdf` to convert an eps file over pdf to a png which you can finally upload.

Answer (score 2):

When you set the terminal you can specify the dash length with the `dl` option, this will also increase the separation between dashes:

```
set term postscript enhanced eps color dl 4
plot sin(x) lw 5 lt 2, cos(x) lw 5 lt 3
```

[image]

You can also add points to better distinguish your graph:

```
set term postscript enhanced eps color
plot "+" u ($1):(sin($1)) w lp lw 5 lt 2 ps 2 pt 7
```

[image]

Comment: The results still don't look. Suppose I want this figure in white and black. I don't see how to see the difference between the two functions at a glance.

Comment: @ziulfer But that's another matter. There are other line types other that `lt 2` and `lt 3`. Also, you could add points to your graph (see newly attached one).

Comment: I want to use colors, but if someone wants to print my graphs in white and black, it is important that they easily see the difference between two curves. Otherwise, I see no point in the use of `lt`. In such case the default value, `lt 1`, for plain lines would be enough. I'm aware of the fact that there are other line types. But once I use `lw` greater than 2 I have very "ugly" results. Moreover I have about 30000 points of data, therefore add points to my graphs won't help very much.

Comment: You don't need to add all the points, using the `every` command you can skip some of them. You can plot the data twice: once with lines only and again with points skipping most of them. Something like this: mcaroba.dyndns.org/misc/08_4.png

Comment: @Miguel You can also use the `pointinterval` options to draw every n-th point, but use every point for the line :)

Comment: @Christoph You know them all!